# Query Concatenated Field (using SubSonic)

Tags: sql, sql-server, subsonic, concatenation

Is there a way to query against a concatenated field using MS SQL? For instance, what I want to do is something like:

```
Select FirstName+' '+LastName as FullName from Attendees where FullName like '%Joe Schmoe%'
```

The above doesn't work. What I have found works is:

```
Select * from Attendee where FirstName+' '+LastName like '%Joe Schmoe%'
```

but I can't figure out how to do that using a SubSonic SqlQuery. I have a number of joins and OR statements added dynamically that I don't want to have to write out the sql manually.

Any help/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it isn't possible in SubSonic

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
SELECT FullName 
FROM (SELECT FirstName+' '+LastName as FullName 
      FROM Attendees) X
WHERE FullName LIKE '%Joe Schmoe%'
```

Comment: Can you point me to how to do that with SubSonic? I have no problem writing a straight SQL query that works. I just need to be able to do it with SubSonic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify your condition in the Where part of your query as follows:

```
List<Attendee> cardHolders = new YourDB()
  .Select
  .From<Attendee>()
  .Where(AttendeeTable.FirstNameColumn + " + ' ' + " + AttendeeTable.SurnameColumn + " AS FullName")
  .Like("%Joe Schmoe%")
  .ExecuteTypedList<Attendee>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this renders sql that looks like "OR FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE @FirstName+''+LastName14" which is an invalid variable declaration.

Comment: Weird, works fine for me. What if you try (AttendeeTable.FirstNameColumn + " + ' ' + " + AttendeeTable.SurnameColumn + " AS FullName")

Answer (score 0):

So late to the game but, if your using the SubSonic Select() you can use the SQL CONCAT to concatenate multiple columns before loading them into your DataTable for your DataGrid so for instance

```
    SubSonic.SqlQuery query = new SubSonic.Select(
     "CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName"
     ).From("Attendees").Where("LastName").Like("%Schmoe%");
    return query;
```

This was something I was looking for as well and just tried to see if the SubSonic would let me use the SQL CONCAT within the Select portion of the SubSonic.SqlQuery. Hope this helps anyone else down the road.